# illegal instruction on exp_expectl with AIX 64 bit

Tags: c, unix, 64-bit, tcl, aix

Please take a look at this simple utility program. It works fine with AIX when compiled to 32 bit using `libexpect5.42` provided by the operating system. 
However, when linking with a 64 bit of libexpect which we manually compiled, we are getting an illegal instruction error on the call to `exp_expectl()`. Any ideas are welcomed.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <expect.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int 
main (int argc, char** argv, char** arge)
{
  int returnValue = 0;
  int iFd = 0;
  int res = 0;
  exp_loguser = 1;
  exp_timeout = 5;
  exp_is_debugging = 0;

  printf("spawning process without argument\n");
  iFd = exp_spawnl ("ls", "ls",(char*)0  );

  printf ("spawned\n");
  printf ("iFd = %d\n", iFd);

  if (iFd < 0)
  {
     printf ("Return %d\n",iFd);
  }
  else
  {
     res = exp_expectl (iFd, exp_glob,"ls", 0, exp_end);
     printf ("Return %d \n",res);
  }
  return iFd;
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head: with 64 bit, it is fairly important to use function prototypes so the compiler knows how to pass things.  The default is to pass them as an int and in 32 bit mode, that works all the time.  In 64 bit mode, it does not work for pointers and longs.  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: SIGILL? That's usually a sign of something catastrophic going wrong, like a stack smash causing the code to return to an unexpected location. You _might_ be best off doing a completely clean build of everything _paying attention to any warnings_. **But why are you trying to do expect from C???**

Comment: Q: SIGILL ? A: Yes we are getting SIGILL. Q: Why are you trying to do expect from C? A: This is legacy code developed a decade ago, the purpose of exp_expectl is to search for data in the stream returned by the spawned command. If you can suggest a better alternative we are willing to try. We already rebuilt libexpect 64 bit from source but it didn't help perhaps we also need to rebuild tcl, what do you think ?

Comment: Figured out eventually that this was a linkage problem with wrong version of tcl